# How to apply fcurve modifiers on top of each other, like object modifiers?

Tags: animation, fcurves

I have a looping animation made up of a few keyframes and a *Cycles* fcurve modifier.

I'd like to introduce some random variations so it doesn't look like an exact loop, however the cycles modifier always appears to be applied last; random patterns produce by the noise modifier are repeated as well:

[image]

Is there a way to do this without adding a ton of empties and constraints?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the NLA?

Add Noise to your original fcurve.

Cycle with strip repeat
Add Noise to the NLA strip

[image: cycle and noise in NLA]

Add Noise to the animated influence

Add noise to the animated strip time.

[image: Noise on animated influence and original Fcurve]

Produces some random patterns over the cycles, with a fair touch of overkill.  Just the repeat and noise modifier in the NLA would suffice.