# Is it possible to make the f-curve noise modifier's scale into a variable?

Tags: graph-editor, fcurves

Normally the scale value in the noise modifier is a constant. It cannot be animated.
[image: Constant scale]

Is it possible to make the scale value decrease over time.
Something like the picture below:
[image: decrease over time]

Any idea or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Envelope modifier**

EDIT: On re-readig the question this is more in regard to strength than scale.

Can add an envelope modifier after the noise modifier.

Set control points to expand or contract accordingly.

Example gif, add a control point limiting noise to [-1, 1] and then at frame 140 expand to [-10, 10]

[image]

For scale one method would be to add modifiers for a series of scales and frame ranges..

[image]

For being able to animate the influence, consider using the NLA editor and keyframe the animated influence

[How to apply fcurve modifiers on top of each other, like object modifiers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39085/how-to-apply-fcurve-modifiers-on-top-of-each-other-like-object-modifiers/39088?r=SearchResults&s=1|51.2504#39088)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but is there a more efficient way to do it than adding many noise modifiers?

Comment: NP.   Things like this are _simplish_ if handled with a script, .. to emulate the logarithmic scale of question image for instance.  Also Look into using the NLA gives option of animated influence and animated strip time.  Been a while since I've used NLA so I posted the old link rather than making an example